# Vim watch file for changes

Tags: colorscheme

Is there a way I can have vim watch something like `/tmp/my-vim` for changes whenever vim is opened to edit any other file and then run a function when the change occurs?

I am looking for a way to tie my *sxhkd* shortcut for switching modes (dark/light, which changes other applications themes) to change currently running vim colorschemes.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! In general, I’m not aware of a builtin mechanism for this. You could use an external tool like entr (your commands would be external commands, so while you could use vim to run some vimscript on the event, it would be in it’s own instance) *or* use a timer to implement an async polling loop, constantly checking timestamps.

Comment: Using a timer solved the problem well enough, every 1/2 second I read the file to see if the flag has been set and is different from the vim's local variable and reset the colours accordingly.

Comment: cool; feel free to add an answer if you’ve solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

Using a timer that regularly read the file for what colour mode is in use I solved the question.

Here is the script that reads and calls the changes:

```
" Set colour scheme (and more) to light mode
function! ColorModeLight()
    colorscheme onehalflight
    let g:color_mode_light=1
    ...
endfunction

" Set colour scheme (and more) to dark mode
function! ColorModeDark()
    colorscheme onehalfdark
    let g:color_mode_light=0
    ...
endfunction

" Check for system colour mode changed
function! ColorModeCheck(timer)
    for line in readfile('/tmp/SYSTEM_LIGHT_MODE', '', 1)
        if line =~ '0' && get(g:, 'color_mode_light', 0) == 1
            call ColorModeDark()
        elseif line =~ '1' && get(g:, 'color_mode_light', 0) == 0
            call ColorModeLight()
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

" Set default colour
colorscheme onehalfdark
let g:color_mode_light=0

...

" Regularly check file for changes
let timer = timer_start(500, 'ColorModeCheck', {'repeat': -1})
```

My *sxhkd* runs a script that truncates and writes either `1` or `0` to `/tmp/SYSTEM_LIGHT_MODE` when called by toggling between the two, after this script is fired vim will soon read that a change occurred and update the colorscheme (lightline and more).